# Upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 . Will the ROS packages i've installed previously be retained ?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have ROS Hydro installed in my ubuntu 12.04 . I'm thinking of upgrading it to Trusty Tahr. I'm worried if i will lose all my packages that i had previously installed. i dont want to take the 'backup all files' route. Can i proceed with the upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will but to be sure just back up the System from terminal backup option and you are done (but be sure to take a full system backup). In backup they create a System Image and it is restored  if there is any fault or the system goes down (Some files and packages not needed by the system are thrown away or replaced by new ones).